# Modify tf-idf vectorizer for some keywords

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, nlp, nltk

I am creating a tf-idf matrix for finding cosine similarity. But I want some frequent words from a set to have more weightage(i.e, tf-idf value).

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
```

How can I modify the above tfidf_matrix for words in a particular set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted tfidf-matrix of csr-type to 2-D array using,

```
my_matrix = tfidf_matrix.toarray()
```

Then, found out the index of keyword using,

```
tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(keyword)
```

After that, Iterated over 2-D matrix and changed the tf-idf value according to requirements. Here, keyword_list contains the index of keywords for which we want to modify the tf-idf value.

```
    for i in range(0, len(my_matrix)):
    for key in keyword_list:
        if key != None:
            key = (int)(key)
        if my_matrix[i][key] > 0.0:
            my_matrix[i][key] = new_value
```

Again, changed my_matrix to csr_type using,

```
tfidf_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(my_matrix)
```

Hence, tfidf_matrix was modified for the list of keywords.